# Cannot integrate parse.com in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to connect my iOS app with parse.com and push notifications. A have added frameworks.
So, compilation fails on

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter getAccessTokenForReverseAuthAsync:localTwitterAccount:] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
      -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter", referenced from:
      -[PF_Twitter getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACAccountStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PF_Twitter.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What is wrong?

Comment: can you add other frameworks like Social.framework ,Accounts.framework etc?

Comment: I have added the next frameworks according to the official guide: AudioToolbox.framework
Foundation.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
CoreLocation.framework
libz.dylib
MobileCoreServices.framework
QuartzCore.framework
Security.framework
StoreKit.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework Bolt.frameworks Parse.framework

Comment: check if your imported parse file is there in build phase tab or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use Twitter and Facebook login, you also have to add the `Social.framework` and the `Accounts.framework`.

Add these frameworks and you should be good to go, this is also mentioned in the documentation [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#twitterusers/iOS).

Comment: That works, but I don understand why in parse.com tutorial no information about that. Why I should import so many frameworks for simple push notification? I dont integrate my app with social networks

Answer (score 1):

Can you add the remaining frameworks from this image, it may solve your issue

[image]

Comment: I do not use the social networks. Why I must add that frameworks?